# MVC 5 Windows 10 Local IIS Debugging not working IIS Express is working

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10

Probably simple but I have tried a number of things to get this going.

My MVC 5 project debugs fine in IIS express on windows 10.. but Local ( Full ) IIS does not debug at all. I am sure I have configured IIS correctly and the project.

Ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to debug ? Are you attaching the process to debugger ?

Comment: Previously I would just run the project in Visual studio 2015. I tried configuring 2 ways - 1) through IIS Manager  and 2 ) Create virtual directory in visual studio.

Comment: You need to start Visual Studio as administrator <shift+right click>

Comment: yes I was already using as admin.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are running visual studio with elevated permissions, you should be able to debug on Local IIS server.

Right click visual studio and select `Run as Administrator`. This will start VS with elevated permissions.

If you are trying to debug an app deployed in IIS without running your VS solution/project in debug mode in visual studio, you need to attach the visual studio debugger to the process which runs your web app in IIS.

Right click visual studio and select `Run as Administrator`

Open a browser and access your site. This will start a new w3wp process for the site if there is not one already.

Open your solution. Put breakpoints. From the menu bar, select `Debug-> Attach to Process`

[image]

Select the w3wp process for your web app.

[image]

Click Attach button and then you can reload your page in browser/perform some action on the page. When code executes the line where you have the breakpoint set, it will stop there and you can do whatever debugging you want to do.

Comment: Really? Why has this changed from windows 7/8?  seems a very convolutedway of doing it!

Comment: @MartinThompson Sorry i misread your question initially. You should be able to debug your solution in VS, if you are running VS with elevated permissions. I verified it in Windows 10 -IIS 10 combo and it works fine.

Comment: ok thanks -  not sure where to start looking. IIS express works.. and Full IIS works   but will not debug.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what i did wrong first time, below steps resolved the issue

I am on win 10, IIS 10.0

Disabled the IIS from windows features

Restart machine

Enable IIS from windows features

Enable internet information services-->world wide web  services->application development features-->check on ASP.NET 4.6 and   all 4.6 related features.(When you select ASP.NET 4.6 all other  dependent features will be selected by default)

from command prompt using elevated privileges/administrator run `aspnet_regiis -i`